# Is the (just-created) [assert] tag meaningful?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question has been posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39125/31503) and tagged with [assert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assert). It is the first assert-tagged question, and the tag appears somewhat relevant, but I am not certain that it adds any significant value.

Already there are edit-suggestions for a full wiki-text on this tag.

Should the question simply be untagged, or is [assert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assert) a meaningful tag?

Answer (score 8):

I would rename the tag to [assertions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assertions).  It would be analogous to [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming), [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments), and [error-handling](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-handling), serving as a flag that the author has particular concerns about that aspect of the code.

**Update:**  Since this is now the highest voted answer here, I've gone ahead and retagged that question with [assertions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assertions).

Answer (score 4):

Does it have a better synonym? For example 'design by contract' isn't a tag. 'error-handling' is an existing tag, however assertions don't 'handle' an error.

Comment: Even though it's not a synonym directly, I do feel that [tag:unit-testing] is strongly related to it.

Answer (score -1):

As ChrisW asks: is there a better synonym?

I have identified [validation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation) as a potential candidate to replace the [assert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assert)

I think it would be reasonable to edit the post, and replace the assert tag with validation tag.

Comment: To me, validation and assertion is not the same thing. You validate input by a user, but you assert that 2 + 2 equals 4.